# How to exclude a chunk from VueJS PWA SW precache?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Currently, I have fresh installation of vuejs app with some test pages and components. All my routes and components are using dynamic imports to load js chunks only when user goes to a particular route or a component is rendered and it is working fine in SPA and SSR mode. The problem occurs in PWA mode when it prefetches all chunks at start.

I have tried 'exclude' function but it still pre-fetched the file.

Is there a way to exclude complete routes e.g. /admin to be pre-fetched? As this is only for internal use and not needed for offline usage.

We are using webpack + workbox bundler.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your question's title to match what you're actually asking. I hope I got it right :)

Yes, that's possible. You can exclude a lazy loaded chunk ("route" or "page" or whatever) from the asset list to be precached.

I assume you're using Vue CLI based project. Look for the PWA config options here https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pwa. It will lead you to whole config of the Vue CLI PWA plugin here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa. That will tell you how to pass any options to the underlying workbox-webpack-plugin. What you need is the `excludeChunks` option, described here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#full_generatesw_config.

Comment: Pate, thanks alot. I tried exactly what you said but it didnt work. I named my component in my src/route file. Then used excludeChunks in my webpack-workbox-plugin options.

Comment: `{
path: '/admin',
component: () => import(/ webpackChunkName: "chunk_admin" / 'layouts/AdminLayout.vue'),
children: [
{ path: '/page3', component: () => import(/ webpackChunkName: "chunk_admin" / 'pages/Index2.vue') },
{ path: '/page4', component: () => import(/ webpackChunkName: "chunk_admin" / 'pages/Index3.vue') }
]
}` @peter

Comment: `workboxOptions: {excludeChunks: ["chunk_admin"]}

Also used "exclude" with and without extention at the end.`

Comment: So the chunk_admin was loaded first time and then when I hit the route /admin then it downloaded again :) (not from cache)

Comment: Well, that's how it works... So you've got a small bug somewhere in your config files :-) One thing to note: it's easier to inspect the built app files in (usually) dist/ directory instead of always trying out the app with the browser. Look at the generated precache-manifest.json file.